# encryption code of java applied in PHP resulting in wrong decryption string

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I am using one encryption/decryption method used in java and applying it in php . I have almost reached to the end but there is one mistake which I found that my decrypted string is not what i was expecting ,
This is my java code

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    public static String encrypt(String message, String key) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (message == null || key == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("text to be encrypted and key should not be null");
        }
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        byte[] messageArr = message.getBytes();
        byte[] keyparam = key.getBytes();

        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyparam, "AES");
        byte[] ivParams = new byte[16];
        byte[] encoded = new byte[messageArr.length + 16];
        System.arraycopy(ivParams, 0, encoded, 0, 16);

        System.arraycopy(messageArr, 0, encoded, 16, messageArr.length);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(ivParams));
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encoded);

        encryptedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedBytes);

        return new String(encryptedBytes);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedStr, String key) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (encryptedStr == null || key == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("text to be decrypted and key should not be null");
        }
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        byte[] keyparam = key.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyparam, "AES");
        byte[] encoded = encryptedStr.getBytes();
        encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
        byte[] decodedEncrypted = new byte[encoded.length - 16];
        System.arraycopy(encoded, 16, decodedEncrypted, 0, encoded.length - 16);
        byte[] ivParams = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(encoded, 0, ivParams, 0, ivParams.length);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(ivParams));
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedEncrypted);
        return new String(decryptedBytes);
    }
```

now i have done this in php like this

```
$encKey = 'encryptionKey';
$cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
$data = 'some data';

$encryption_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);

$iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);

$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size);

$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($data), 'aes-256-cbc', $encKey, $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
//$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($data), $cipher, $encKey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

$encrypted_data = base64_encode($iv . $ciphertext_raw);

print_r($encrypted_data);
```

now the problem is when i encrypt one string in php and decrypt it in java code it add some escape sequence but when i encrypt that same string in java and decrypt it in java it is proper and accurate and i am not sure why this is happening ... may be i am doing some thing wrong
as I have to do this encryption in php using java code i am not sure that is this process going in right way or there is some error .

this is the string which i am encrypting

```
String str = "vendor_id=INT_GTW&format=json&msg_code=KBEX99&data={\"header\":{\"msg_code\":\"KBEX99\",\"source\":\"INSTANTPAY\",\"channel\":\"CONBNK\",\"txn_ref_number\":\"INSTANTPAY_CONBNK_00001\",\"txn_datetime\":\"1498118309808\",\"ip\":\"1\",\"device_id\":\"XYWZPQR123\",\"api_version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"detail\":{\"entity\":\"INSTANTPAY\",\"intent\":\"REG\",\"user_identifier\":\"INSTANTPAY28423928\",\"crn\":\"105683710\",\"p1\":\"105683710\",\"p2\":\"\",\"p3\":\"INSTANTPAY\",\"p4\":\"\",\"p5\":\"\",\"p6\":\"\",\"p7\":\"\",\"p8\":\"\",\"p9\":\"\",\"p10\":\"\",\"p11\":\"\",\"p12\":\"\",\"p13\":\"\",\"p14\":\"\",\"p15\":\"\",\"p16\":\"\",\"p17\":\"\",\"p18\":\"\",\"p19\":\"\",\"p20\":\"\"}}";

and this is decrypted string 

vendor_id=INT_GTW&format=json&msg_code=KBEX99&data={"header":{"msg_code":"KBEX99","source":"INSTANTPAY","channel":"CONBNK","txn_ref_number":"INSTANTPAY_CONBNK_00001","txn_datetime":"1498118309808","ip":"1","device_id":"XYWZPQR123","api_version":"1.0.0"},"detail":{"entity":"INSTANTPAY","intent":"REG","user_identifier":"INSTANTPAY28423928","crn":"105683710","p1":"105683710","p2":"","p3":"INSTANTPAY","p4":"","p5":"","p6":"","p7":"","p8":"","p9":"","p10":"","p11":"","p12":"","p13":"","p14":"","p15":"","p16":"","p17":"","p18":"","p19":"","p20":""}}

but when i am doing it in php and decrypting 

"vendor_id=INT_GTW&format=json&msg_code=KBEX99&data={\"header\":{\"msg_code\":\"KBEX99\",\"source\":\"INSTANTPAY\",\"channel\":\"CONBNK\",\"txn_ref_number\":\"INSTANTPAY_CONBNK_00001\",\"txn_datetime\":\"1498118309808\",\"ip\":\"1\",\"device_id\":\"XYWZPQR123\",\"api_version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"detail\":{\"entity\":\"INSTANTPAY\",\"intent\":\"REG\",\"user_identifier\":\"INSTANTPAY28423928\",\"crn\":\"105683710\",\"p1\":\"105683710\",\"p2\":\"\",\"p3\":\"INSTANTPAY\",\"p4\":\"\",\"p5\":\"\",\"p6\":\"\",\"p7\":\"\",\"p8\":\"\",\"p9\":\"\",\"p10\":\"\",\"p11\":\"\",\"p12\":\"\",\"p13\":\"\",\"p14\":\"\",\"p15\":\"\",\"p16\":\"\",\"p17\":\"\",\"p18\":\"\",\"p19\":\"\",\"p20\":\"\"}}"

i am getting this
```

So any encryption decryption expert please help me in this ...
Thank you !!

Comment: If you pass the plaintext in the PHP code 1:1 as in the Java code (as string, in quotes, with `\"` inside) no `json_encode()` is needed (because this also encodes the backslash). If your plaintext has a different format, post an example.

Comment: yes i think this was the error ....